I would like to package a .ps1 script and a .exe into one package
I have two files and I would like to combine them into one file.  These are my two files:
1 = script.ps1
2 = installer.exe
The script does some things and then the script proceeds to run installer.exe.  This package will simply be run by computer administrators manually.
How can I create one package that will pop off the script?

What installer script does the installer currently use?

Try 7z SFX Builder, it can allow you to create a self-extracting .exe that upon extracting both files will launch the script you specify.
